# PHP Composer Not Working On Mac

Tags: php, mac-osx, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I have installed a bitnami mac stack mainly because I require at least PHP 5.4.7 version for my project. However, I have run into an issue with composer. This is the error I get when I run:

```
php composer.phar install --dev
```

The error:

```
Richard-Knops-MacBook-Pro:my-project richardknop$ php composer.phar install --dev
dyld: Library not loaded: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/php
  Reason: Incompatible library version: php requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0
Trace/BPT trap
Richard-Knops-MacBook-Pro:my-project richardknop$
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

As the message fairly clearly indicates, you need to upgrade your `libiconv` to 8.x. http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/